# How to update a screen RIGHT BEFORE showing it up using Navigator.pop()?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a switch in every screen of the app that enables/disable dark mode in the whole app.

I'm trying to use Navigator.push() to navigate to the second screen, and Navigator.pop() to go back, it is pretty simple. but...

I always face the same problem. I see the first page updating in my face right after the pop() animation finishes. It is weird looking (like a blink). The point is: When I go back to the first page I want to see the changes I made already there.

Here is the code in case you need it.

```
//first_page.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'second_page.dart';

class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstPage({super.key, required this.darkMode});

  final bool darkMode;

  @override
  State<FirstPage> createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
  late final ValueNotifier<bool> darkMode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    darkMode = ValueNotifier(widget.darkMode);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(actions: [
        Switch(
          value: darkMode.value,
          onChanged: (bool newValue) {
            setState(
              () => darkMode.value = newValue,
            );
          },
        )
      ]),
      body: Container(
        color: darkMode.value ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
        child: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () async {
              bool? isDark = await Navigator.push<bool?>(context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                return SecondPage(
                  darkMode: darkMode.value,
                );
              }));

              setState(() {
                darkMode.value = isDark!;
              });
            },
            child: Text(
              "Go to page 2",
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

```
//second_page.dart

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const SecondPage({super.key, required this.darkMode});

  final bool darkMode;

  @override
  State<SecondPage> createState() => SecondPageState();
}

class SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  late final ValueNotifier<bool> darkMode;

  @override
  void dispose() {
    darkMode.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    darkMode = ValueNotifier(widget.darkMode);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(actions: [
        Switch(
          value: darkMode.value,
          onChanged: (bool newValue) async{
            setState(
              () => darkMode.value = newValue,
            );
          },
        )
      ]),
      body: Container(
        color: darkMode.value ? Colors.white : Colors.black,
        child: Center(
          child: ElevatedButton(
            onPressed: () {
              Navigator.pop(context, darkMode.value);
            },
            child: Text(
              "Pop back",
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

I have tried sharing widgets, sharing value notifiers, returning true/false from the Navigator.pop(context,value)...

The only way around I have found is using Navigator.push to SecondScreen, which has a button to Navigate.push again to the FirstScreen.

I just want to know if I'm missing something... Thanks for your help!
[This GIF shows the issue I described](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rIDb.gif)

Comment: Have you tried storing it in a provider or riverpod type state instead of a value notifier?

Comment: This is what state management libraries are for. As in the above comment, you should try provider/riverpod. There are many ways to resolve your issue but for long run, you should consider using any of the state management solutions.

Comment: Yes, if your screen is being built from data structures that notify either via Listenable (core) or ProviderListenable (riverpod), the screen has already been updated before you get there.

Answer (score 1):

If you use Flutter `Navigator` you can use `whenComplete` right after your `push` method. It will execute the code when returning to the page (after `context.pop()` on the other page)

**Example**:

```
onPressed: () {
        Navigator.of(context)
            .push(
          SecondPage.route(darkMode: darkMode),
        )
            .whenComplete(() {
          // execute some code when returning to the page
        });
      },
```

**Docs**:

You can use async function here as well.

[docs](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/TickerFuture/whenComplete.html)

**Suggestion**:
To make code cleaner you can move your `MaterialPageRoute` to separate method (let's call it `route`) in the `SecondPage` class.

```
class SecondPage extends StatelessWidget {
  const SecondPage({
    super.key,
    required this.darkMode,
  });

  final bool darkMode;

  static Route<void> route({
    required bool darkMode,
  }) {
    return MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (context) => SecondPage(
        darkMode: darkMode,
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct code guys. I had to move the Notifier to a higher level in the widget hierarchy. In most cases your answers would work just fine. But, Since the **AppBar** is not inside of the body of the Scaffold, it wouldnt work the way i expected it to work.

In this case I solved it moving the notifier to app-level context so it rebuilds the whole FirstPageWidget.

During the pop animation it would show the old state until its finished the slide animation or whatever. That was the problem guys, remember. Here's a way around I found to the issue but that its not as perfect in my opinion since you would have to Navigator.pushReplacement() to FirstPage from FirstPage,

```
    class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  
  ValueNotifier<bool> darkMode = ValueNotifier<bool>(false);
  late MySwitch mySwitch;
  

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    
    widget.mySwitch= MySwitch(darkMode: widget.darkMode,);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(

        primarySwatch: Colors.amber,
      ),
      home:  FirstPage(darkMode: widget.darkMode,),
    );
  }
}
```

Another aproach but it's a way around. I'd use the first one if possible.
The way i did it is using pushReplacement() instead of pop() to the SecondPage . And then, to go back, instead of pop() in the SecondPage I did pushReplacement() to the FirstPage. You would manually have to implement the back button as shown:

```
    class FirstPage extends StatefulWidget {
  FirstPage({super.key, required this.darkMode, required this.mySwitch});

  DarkMode darkMode;
  MySwitch mySwitch;

  @override
  State<FirstPage> createState() => _FirstPageState();
}

    class _FirstPageState extends State<FirstPage> {
      Color color = Colors.red;
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
    
        if (widget.darkMode.value) {
          color = Colors.black;
        } else {
          color = Colors.red;
        }
    
        widget.darkMode.addListener(() {
          setState(() {
            if (widget.darkMode.value) {
              color = Colors.black;
            } else 

    {
                  color = Colors.red;
                }
              });
            });
          }
        
          @override
          Widget build(BuildContext context) {
            return Scaffold(
              floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(onPressed: () async {
                Navigator.pushReplacement(
                  context,
                  MaterialPageRoute(
                    builder: (context) => SecondPage(
                      darkMode: widget.darkMode,
                      mySwitch: widget.mySwitch,
                    ),
                  ),
                );
              }),
              appBar: AppBar(
                actions: [widget.mySwitch],
              ),
              body: SizedBox.expand(
                  child: Container(
                color: color,
              )), 
            );
          }
        }


    class SecondPage extends StatefulWidget {
  SecondPage({super.key, required this.darkMode, required this.mySwitch});

  DarkMode darkMode;
  MySwitch mySwitch;

  @override
  State<SecondPage> createState() => _SecondPageState();
}

class _SecondPageState extends State<SecondPage> {
  Color color = Colors.red;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();

    if (widget.darkMode.value) {
      color = Colors.black;
    } else {
      color = Colors.red;
    }

    widget.darkMode.addListener(() {
      setState(() {
        if (widget.darkMode.value) {
          color = Colors.black;
        } else {
          color = Colors.red;
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  void setState(VoidCallback fn) {
    if (!mounted) return;
    super.setState(fn);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pushReplacement(
              context,
              MaterialPageRoute(
                builder: (context) => FirstPage(
                  darkMode: widget.darkMode,
                  mySwitch: widget.mySwitch,
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
        actions: [
          widget.mySwitch,
        ],
      ),
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: Container(
          color: color,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```